# Js Как добавить div в Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть див

```
<div class=”container”></div>
```

нужно создать ещё 3 дива в диве с классом `container`, названием, и **(позицией тега ) вот это во обще не понял**.
пробовал сделать так:

```
var colorArray2 = document.getElementsByClassName('container');

var element = ('<div class="element">Element</div>');

var colorArray2 = document.body.getElementsByClassName("container");
for(var i = 0; i < colorArray2.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        var div = document.createElement(element);
        colorArray2[i].appendChild(element);
        console.log(colorArray2[i])
    }
}
```

Не работает.
Ругается на  эту строчку `var element = ('<div class="element">Element</div>');`

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('<div class="element">Element</div>') is not a valid name.
    at HTMLDocument.createElement (<anonymous>:1:1554)
    at http://localhost:63342/JsTest/script.js:116:28
(anonymous) @ VM464:1
(anonymous) @ script.js:116
```

Как это можно сделать? Если можно то пример на js и jquery.

Comment: Возможно потому что в var div криейт елемент ты доставляешь строку с кодом а должена ьыть строка с тегом var div = document.createElement('div'); div.classList.add('element'); div.innerText = 'Element';

Comment: А переменная element тебе не нужна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function createElementsInside() {
  var colorArray2 = document.body.getElementsByClassName("container");
  for (var i = 0; i < colorArray2.length; i++) {
    var innerHtml = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      innerHtml += '<div class="element">Element</div>';
    }
    colorArray2[i].innerHTML = innerHtml;
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.element {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: lightgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<button onclick="createElementsInside()" type="button">Create Elements Inside</button>
```

```js
function createElementsInside() {
  var colorArray2 = document.body.getElementsByClassName("container");
  for (var i = 0; i < colorArray2.length; i++) {
    colorArray2[i].innerHTML = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.setAttribute("class", "element");
      div.textContent = "Element";
      colorArray2[i].appendChild(div);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.element {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background: lightgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
<button onclick="createElementsInside()" type="button">Create Elements Inside</button>
```

```js
function createElementsInside() {
  var innerHtml = "";
  for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    innerHtml += '<div class="element">Element</div>';
  }
  $(".container").html(innerHtml);
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.element {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: lightgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
<button onclick="createElementsInside()" type="button">Create Elements Inside</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Спасибо работает!!! F? А, не могли бы ещё тот же пример на jquery? Добавить.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: @EugeneTM На здоровье. Успехов!

Comment: @EugeneTM, зачем вам jquery? пользуйтесь vanilla-js

Comment: @dasauser  Я не знаю что это???

Comment: @EugeneTM, мощный js-фреймворк. google в помощь.

Comment: @dasauser мне бы с этим справиться!!! Почитаю! Спасибо!!!