# Как вынести элемент за пределы блока с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
function createElementsInside() {
    var colorArray2 = document.body.getElementsByClassName("container");
    for (var i = 0; i < colorArray2.length; i++) {
        var innerHtml = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            innerHtml += '<div class="element">Element</div>';
        }
        innerHtml += '<input id="btn" type="button" value="+">';
        colorArray2[i].innerHTML = innerHtml;

        console.log(colorArray2[i])
    }
}
```

Как тег `input` вынести за пределы дива?

Сейчас в консоль выводит так:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="element">Element</div>
    <div class="element">Element</div>
    <div class="element">Element</div>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="+">
</div
```

А, нужно так:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="element">Element</div>
    <div class="element">Element</div>
    <div class="element">Element</div>      
</div>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="+">
```

Переделал из вопроса [Как вставить div](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/894103/js-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-div-%D0%B2-div?noredirect=1#comment1461999_894103)

**Что не так?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function createElementsInsideAndButton() {
  var colorArray2 = document.body.getElementsByClassName("container");
  for (var i = 0; i < colorArray2.length; i++) {
    var innerHtml = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      innerHtml += '<div class="element">Element</div>';
    }
    colorArray2[i].innerHTML += innerHtml;

    var btn = document.createElement("input");
    btn.id = "btn"; // wrong - duplicate id's
    btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
    btn.value = "+";
    colorArray2[i].parentNode.insertBefore(btn, colorArray2[i].nextSibling);
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.element {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background: lightgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createElementsInsideAndButton()" type="button">Create Elements Inside</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!!! А, не мог бы, подробней объяснить, построчно ,что происходит! Немного не понимаю самих действий. Особенно с btn.

Comment: @EugeneTM Любой DOM-элемент можно создать с помощью вызова `document.createElement`. Затем - устанавливаем нужные свойства нового элемента. И наконец, добавляем новый элемент в родителя `colorArray2[i]` перед элементом, который идет сразу за `colorArray2[i]`.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде понял!

Comment: вот эту строчку не понял только `.parentNode.insertBefore(btn, colorArray2[i].nextSibling);`

Comment: parentNode это что? и nextSibiling

Comment: @EugeneTM ... добавляем новый элемент в родителя `colorArray2[i]` перед элементом, который идет сразу за `colorArray2[i]`.

Comment: Спасибо!!! я Добавил две строчки `console.log(colorArray2[i])
        console.log(btn)`  и в консоли всё появляется А, почему  на странице появляется только input? А, не блок div с 3 элементами и после инпут?

Comment: @EugeneTM Вы говорите о своем коде или о примере кода в ответе?

Comment: да о примере просто в него я добавил две строчки.

Comment: @EugeneTM тогда я не понял вопроса. В ответе для каждого контейнера появляются 3 элемента внутри и кнопка снаружи.

Comment: Да, а, на странице отображается 3 элемента (div) и input а, после нажатия на + в консоли появляться ещё такой же элемента (div) и input  но на странице  только +,  я думаю что дивы появляются, просто на том же месте может быть такое? Может их как то сдвинуть можно?

Comment: @EugeneTM Изменил код в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо всё как нужно!!! Тогда так же  можно и атрибут value убрать из html и всё заработает. Правильно я понял? В предыдущем примере

Comment: @EugeneTM не понял про атрибут value, чей атрибут value?

Comment: В предыдущем примере было вот так `<input onclick="createElementsInside()" id="btn" type="button" value="+">` Я убрал из этого тега атрибут value появился серый квадратик и работает так же.

Comment: @EugeneTM да, value, в данном случае, не имеет значения

Comment: Спасибо! За разъяснение!!!